# Stop showing Welcome to Gradle message from output

Tags: gradle, gradle-task

I am running gradle commands from command line and I want to show only output. There is an option -q, -quiet which says it will log errors only. After running command I get this crap with output too. How can I stop this ??

```
Welcome to Gradle 2.11.

To run a build, run gradle <task> ...

To see a list of available tasks, run gradle tasks

To see a list of command-line options, run gradle --help

To see more detail about a task, run gradle help --task <task>
```

Comment: What gradle version are you using? I am running 2.12 and the only output I see is stuff our tests write out - none of the Gradle messages. Ran: "./gradlew -q clean build"

Comment: Interesting that I do see the message you are talking about when I just run: "./gradlew -q" without a specified task.

Comment: I am running it with task but still getting same message.

Comment: Hmm... I just tried 2.9 and still had the message suppressed. Can you share the actual command line you are running? And when you run it with a task does it run the task?

Comment: I have a task which creates Zip archive of current folder. It works fine i.e creates zip

Answer (score 6):

In Gradle 7.5 there is a new flag that can be set in `gradle.properties`

> **`org.gradle.welcome=(never,once)`**
>
> Controls whether Gradle should print a welcome message. If set to *never* then the welcome message will be suppressed. If set to *once* then the message is printed once for each new version of Gradle. *Default is `once`*.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties

You can set this property in several ways. The first one found wins.

- command line, as set using the -P / --project-prop environment options.
- `gradle.properties` in `GRADLE_USER_HOME` directory.
- `gradle.properties` in project root directory.
- `gradle.properties` in Gradle installation directory.

So, to suppress this in CI/CD add

```properties
org.gradle.welcome=never
```

to `$projectDir/gradle.properties`

Answer (score 4):

Workaround for this, you can simply run `gradle --version` first before running your command.

Example:

```
gradle --version # the welcome message will appear here
gradle -q mycommand # there should be no welcome message anymore
```

EDIT:
Workaround from gradle github issues: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5213#issuecomment-391976595

Answer (score 3):

This can be configured in file `gradle.properties`:

```
systemProp.org.gradle.internal.launcher.welcomeMessageEnabled=false
```